# Remove all words bigger than 6 characters using sed

Tags: sed

I'm new to sed and I'm trying to figure out a way to remove the words in a text with more than 6 characters.

So far I've come up with this but it just gives me an empty file.

```
sed -n '/.\{6\}/!d' input > output
```

> **Input**
>
> But it is sed's ability to filter text in a pipeline which particularly distinguishes it from other types of editors.
>
> **Desired output**
>
> But it is sed's to text in a which it from other types of.

Comment: Fundamentally, `sed` is line oriented. Your script will delete any *line* which doesn't match the regex. Fortunately, `s///g` allows you to substitute all matches in a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick to remove words containing more than six letters - if you define a word as being made up of letters A-Z and a-z:

```
sed -e s'/[A-Za-z]\{7,\}//g'
```

Comment: This one worked as well.
what are you "telling" sed to do in the [A-Za-z]\{7,\} part?

Comment: Um, delete words which are seven characters or longer? That is, substitute any match on the regex with nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try

```
sed -r 's/\b\w{6,}\s?\b//g'
```

For your example:

```
$ echo "But it is sed's ability to filter text in a pipeline which particularly distinguishes it from other types of editors."  | sed -r 's/\b\w{6,}\s?\b//g'
But it is sed's to text in a which it from other types of .
```

EDIT: The above would remove words that are *6 characters or longer*.  You might want to modify `{6,}` in the expression above to suit your needs.

Comment: It worked perfectly. thanks.
Can you explain me what is sed doing?

Comment: \b denotes a word boundary. \w denotes a word character. \s? would match an optional space after the word.