# Remove Words Shorter Than 4 Characters Using Linux

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, sed

I have read the following and tried to rework the command logic for what I want. But, I just haven't been able to get it right.

[Delete the word whose length is less than 2 in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417663/delete-the-word-whose-length-is-less-than-2-in-bash)

Tried: `echo $example | sed -e 's/ [a-zA-Z0-9]\{4\} / /g'`

[Remove all words bigger than 6 characters using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19209956/remove-all-words-bigger-than-6-characters-using-sed)

Tried: `sed -e s'/[A-Za-z]\{,4\}//g'`

---

Please help me with a simple `awk` or `sed` command for the following:

`Here is an example line of fantastic data`

And get:

`Here example line fantastic data`

Comment: Why weren't you able to apply the answers to suit your logic? I am sure it is _not_ quite tough. What did you try ?

Comment: Yes, those were my failed attempts to rework the logic. First one really doesn't work. Second one seems like I'm just missing it.

Comment: `sed -E 's/\b\w{1,3}\b[[:blank:]]*//g' file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ echo Here is an example line of fantastic data | sed -E 's/\b\(\w\)\{,3\}\b\s*//g'
Here is an example line of fantastic data
```

Comment: Ah, this is perfect since I'm piping my data though in a script. Would you like to add the code to take out the spaces? I'll mark you correct. If not, I can just do that in another pipe. Either way, appreciate the quick help.

Comment: @DomainsFeatured i have piped through one more sed command to remove the extra spaces.

Comment: You can just use multiple sed commands in one go, separated by `;`, instead of spawning another subshell with a pipe.

Comment: @stevesliva Thanks for the input.  I was not happy with the second pipe too. Modified my answer.

Comment: @HakanBaba - well, it's only helpful if it works... I actually was trying my idea and ended up on `sed 's/\b\w\{1,3\}\b\s*//g'`.   The prior suggestion deletes all the whitespace entirely.  And I don't see that `-E` is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you store the sentence in a variable, you can iterate through it in a for loop. Then you can evaluate if each word is greater than 2 characters.

```
sentence="Here is an example line of fantastic data";
for word in $sentence; do
    if [ ${#word} -gt 2]; then
        echo -n $word;
        echo -n " ";
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a BASH example of how to do it if you have a lot of sentences in a file which would be the most common case right?

#### SCRIPT (Remove words with two letters or shorter)

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do

    echo "$line" | sed -E 's/\b\w{1,2}\b//g' 

done < <( cat sentences.txt )
```

#### INPUT

```
$  cat sentences.txt
Edgar Allan Poe (January 19, 1809 to October 7, 1849) was an
American writer, poet, critic and editor best known for evocative
short stories and poems that captured the imagination and interest
of readers around the world. His imaginative storytelling and tales
of mystery and horror gave birth to the modern detective story.

Many of Poe’s works, including “The Tell-Tale Heart” and
“The Fall of the House of Usher,” became literary classics. Some
aspects of Poe’s life, like his literature, is shrouded in mystery,
and the lines between fact and fiction have been blurred substantially
since his death.
```

#### OUTPUT

```
$ ./grep_tests.sh
Edgar Allan Poe (January , 1809  October , 1849) was
American writer, poet, critic and editor best known for evocative
short stories and poems that captured the imagination and interest
 readers around the world. His imaginative storytelling and tales
 mystery and horror gave birth  the modern detective story.

Many  Poe’ works, including “The Tell-Tale Heart” and
“The Fall  the House  Usher,” became literary classics. Some
aspects  Poe’ life, like his literature,  shrouded  mystery,
and the lines between fact and fiction have been blurred substantially
since his death.
```